# Meaning of push registers with segment and offset

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, i386

i want to create MBR with assembly language . But i have code , give by somebody that i don't understand .
When you write

```
push ax
push bx
```

What is the meaning , when we use segment and offset

For more details, read this code :

```
    [BITS 16]
[ORG 0x0]

mov ax, 0x07C0
mov ds , ax
mov es , ax
mov ax , 0x8000
mov ss , ax
mov sp , 0xf000

mov si ,msgDebut
call afficher

end :
    jmp end

msgDebut db "HelloWorld!!!!",13,10,0

afficher :
    push ax
    push bx

.debut :
    lodsb
    cmp al ,0
    jz .fin
    mov ah , 0x0E
    mov bx , 0x07
    int 0x10
    jmp .debut

.fin :
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret

times 510-($-$$) db 144
    dw 0xAA55
```

can you explain me this code line by line using memory addressing, segmentation, and offset abstraction

Comment: Explaining every line in this code is like a complete course in assembly programming. Please narrow it down. What in particular are you struggling with?

Comment: In fact my problem in particular is at the level of

push ax
push bx

What are these instructions for?

Answer (score 3):

The `push` instruction places its operand on the stack for conservation.
The stack is an area of memory set aside for this purpose.

The stackpointer determines **where** the data will be stored in memory.
  When the stackpointer `SS:SP` is equal to 0x8000:0xEFFE, `push ax` will first lower the stackpointer by 2 so it becomes 0x8000:0xEFFC and then write the contents of the `AX` register in that memory address.
Hereafter `push bx` will again lower the stackpointer by 2 so it now becomes 0x8000:0xEFFA and then write the contents of the `BX` register in that memory address.

The `pop` instruction reverses the actions of `push`. You use these to restore the registers to their original values.

```
afficher :
    push ax   ; Preserve AX
    push bx   ; Preserve BX
    ...
    pop bx    ; Restore BX
    pop ax    ; Restore AX
    ret
```